# Как правильно записать значение в файл несколько раз

Tags: java

Подскажите, как правильно можно реализовать программу. Мне необходимо записать значение в файл несколько раз. На данном этапе я могу записать один раз и после этого, если я желаю добавить ещё один товар у меня перезаписывается строка. Можно ли сделать через рекурсию и всё в одном классе ?

```
public class Basket {
public  void backTovar(String katal) throws IOException {
    File file = new File("G:/Catalog2.txt");
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("G:/Catalog2.txt"));
    String mes = switch (katal) {
        case "1" -> "Товар Штаны (чёрного цвета) добавлен в корзину";
        case "2" -> "Товар Штаны (желтого цвета) добавлен в корзину";
        case "3" -> "Товар Майка (белого цвета) добавлен в корзину";
        case "4" -> "Товар Майка (чёрного цвета) добавлен в корзину";
        case "5" -> "Товар Галстук (розового цвета) добавлен в корзину";
        case "6" -> "Товар Галстук (чёрного цвета) добавлен в корзину";
        case "7" -> "Товар Часы (белого цвета) добавлен в корзину";
        case "8" -> "Товар Часы (серого цвета) добавлен в корзину";
        default -> "Неизвестный товар : " + katal;
    };
    System.out.println(mes);
    writer.write(mes);
    System.out.println(" would you like add goods? (yes/no) ");
   /* String result = bufferedReader.readLine();
    if(result.equals("yes")){
        System.out.println("Input number goods " );
        String katal = bufferedReader.readLine();
        return backTovar(String katal);
    }*/
writer.close();
}
```

}

Comment: Ну так прочитай из файла и добавляй к прочитанной строке. Потом её записывай.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы писать в конец файла, не перезаписывая содержимое файла, передайте вторым аргументом флаг `append` в [конструктор `FileWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter-java.io.File-boolean-):

```java
new FileWriter("G:/Catalog2.txt", true)
```

Comment: а есть ли возможность писать второе значение с новой строки, передавая вторым аргументом флаг append?

Comment: Конечно, вы можете писать в файл символ переноса строки `\n`, там где это вам нужно: `writer.write("\n");`. Либо использовать метод [`writer.newLine();`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#newLine()), который будет писать нужный перенос строки в зависимости от ОС (`\r\n` для Windows или `\n` для Unix-систем).

Answer (score 1):

Рекурсия здесь представляется излишней, так как приведёт к повторному переоткрытию/закрытию файла и новой обёртки для потока ввода.
Эффективнее и корректнее было бы передать в качестве аргумента название файла, в который будут сохраняться данные, и использовать обычный цикл.
Также для корректного закрытия ресурсов следует применить `try-with-resources`, а для работы с консолью достаточно использовать сканер, а не буферизированный поток:

```java
public void backTovar(String fileName) throws IOException {
    File file = new File(fileName);
    try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file))) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String answer = "yes";
        while ("yes".equalsIgnoreCase(answer)) {
            System.out.println("Input goods ID: ");
            String katal = scanner.nextLine();

            String message = switch (katal) {
                case "1" -> "Товар Штаны (чёрного цвета) добавлен в корзину";
                case "2" -> "Товар Штаны (желтого цвета) добавлен в корзину";
                case "3" -> "Товар Майка (белого цвета) добавлен в корзину";
                case "4" -> "Товар Майка (чёрного цвета) добавлен в корзину";
                case "5" -> "Товар Галстук (розового цвета) добавлен в корзину";
                case "6" -> "Товар Галстук (чёрного цвета) добавлен в корзину";
                case "7" -> "Товар Часы (белого цвета) добавлен в корзину";
                case "8" -> "Товар Часы (серого цвета) добавлен в корзину";
                default -> "Неизвестный товар : " + katal;
            };
            System.out.println(message);
            writer.write(message);
            writer.newLine(); // добавить новую строку!

            System.out.println("Would you like to add more goods? (yes/no)");
            answer = scanner.nextLine();
        }
    }
}
```

При необходимости *добавлять* строки в файл при записи, можно установить режим `append` в конструкторе `FileWriter`, как указано в [ответе выше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1510533/386633) или даже параметризовать сам метод:

```java
public void backTovar(String fileName, boolean append) throws IOException {
    File file = new File(fileName);
    try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, append))) {
        // ...
    }
}
```